# Refresh the List View when an item is removed

Tags: android

I have a ListView which is showing me some data through an array (add and remove)

Whenever I delete an element from the ListView through context menu, the list is not refreshing but the element is deleted from the array. How can I refresh the list to show that the item is removed at the moment itself?

**Code**

```
public class FavouritesLisViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<NewsModel> {



    public FavouritesLisViewAdapter(Context context, List<NewsModel> newsModel){
        super(context, R.layout.home_fragment,newsModel);

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.favourites_custom_row,parent,false);

        final NewsModel singleNews = getItem(position);
        TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewFav);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.idFavmage);
        ImageView filledHeart = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.favImage);
        final ListView favListView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.favouriteLV) ;

        filledHeart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //implementation to change status back to 1(negative)
                DBHelper db=new DBHelper(getContext());
                String id=singleNews.getId();
                db.reverseUpdateFavourites(id);
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Item removed from favourites",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });


        title.setText(singleNews.getTitle());
        Picasso.get().load(singleNews.getUrlToImage()).into(image);

        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you deleting the element from the arraylist that you have used to set adapter?

Comment: Yes. I am deleting an item by clicking an delete icon. Although item get removed the listview does not get updated at the moment itself.  @sanjeev

Comment: "Whenever I delete an element from the ListView through context menu" – Where is this context menu? How are you handling the delete there?

Comment: `ListView` is a legacy component. You have to use `RecyclerView` https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview

Comment: In my app there are 2 fragments called Home Fragment and Wish list Fragment. I am adding news items to wishlist adapter by clicking an icon by displaying a tost message. And the issue I have in wishlist fragment is to removing added items. In wishlist fragment, when I clicked the remove icon in relavant item or items it displays toast messages.That means the item gets removed from the db. The issue I ave is to show those changes in wishlist fragment without manually refreshing the fragment. Once I refreshed by myself, can see changes there.  @Mike M.

Comment: OK, but where is the context menu you mentioned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out this code.

Extend your `ListAdapter` to `BaseAdapter` and pass the list to that adapter.

```
    private class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        final Context context;
        List<NewsModel> newsModelList = new ArrayList();
        View view;
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

        private ListAdapter(Context context, List<NewsModel> newsModel) {
            this.context = context;
            this.newsModelList = newsModel;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return newsModelList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.favourites_custom_row,parent,false);

        final NewsModel singleNews = getItem(position);
        TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewFav);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.idFavmage);
        ImageView filledHeart = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.favImage);
        final ListView favListView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.favouriteLV) ;

        filledHeart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //implementation to change status back to 1(negative)
                DBHelper db=new DBHelper(getContext());
                String id=singleNews.getId();
                db.reverseUpdateFavourites(id);
              ///// ADD THIS LINE  ///////
                newsModelList.remove(Integer.valueOf(id));
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Item removed from favourites",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });


        title.setText(singleNews.getTitle());
        Picasso.get().load(singleNews.getUrlToImage()).into(image);

        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use following method to notify adapter that a single item is removed.

```
notifyItemRemoved(position);
```

Use following method to notify adapter that a range has been removed(multiple items in a sequence has been removed).

```
notifyItemRangeRemoved(position, count);
```

Answer (score 0):

Call notifyDataSetChanged() on your adapter object. Or use Recyclerview, In RecyclerView.Adapter different methods are available to refresh list UI. Like notifyItemRemoved (int position), notifyItemRangeRemoved(int, int), notifyItemChanged(int) etc. Choose the one suitable to your requirement.

Comment: I have called notifyDataSetChanged(). Could you please help me for placing the method properly in the object . @user320676

Comment: To help you further I need to see your activity/fragment code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete an item from a recycler view, the best practice is to remove the object from the list in your ViewModel/Presenter and then update the list in the adapter in order to update the list UI.

Answer (score -1):

You delete data from the database, I think you don't update a list of data which you pass in an adapter, try to reload adapter with updated data list.